# Only white screen being displayed when calling a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making a login page with fragments but whenever i run the application i am only getting a white scree,no edittext no buttons nuthing.

LoginFragment

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private Button btcancel;
    private EditText etpassword;
    private Button btlogin;
    private EditText etusername;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_frag,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    private void initialize() {

        btcancel = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bt_cancel);
        etpassword = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        btlogin = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bt_login);
        etusername = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.et_user_name);
    }
}
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragmentSetUp();
    }

    private void fragmentSetUp() {
        fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        LoginFragment loginFragment=new LoginFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(loginFragment,"login").commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a parent layout to put a fragment, but in your case you can use the default layout of android as a parent container for the fragment.

**solution:**

```
    fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    LoginFragment loginFragment=new LoginFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content,loginFragment,"login").commit();
```

Comment: @Anuj for me, yes, it is to create more depth in your design.

Comment: @Anuj yes you need to also set it as a layout in your activity by calling the setContentView(). follow this thread to get you started http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

it probably because you missed `setContentView` for the `activity` . Inside the layout you should declare a container where you can add/replace `Fragment`s. Also in LoginFragment you are using getActivity to retrieve the Fragment's component. You should use the inflated view. The best way, imo, is to override `onCreatedView`

Comment: but i have created only 1 layout for the login activity

Answer (score 0):

You can also use -

```
fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    LoginFragment loginFragment=new LoginFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(0,loginFragment,"login").commit();
```

*Fragment Transaction -*

> **public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment
> fragment, String tag)**
>
> Added in API level 11 Add a fragment to the activity state. This
> fragment may optionally also have its view (if Fragment.onCreateView
> returns non-null) into a container view of the activity.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *containerViewId* - Optional identifier of the container this fragment is
> to be placed in. If 0, it will not be placed in a container.
>
> *fragment* -  The fragment to be added. This fragment must not  already
> be added to the activity.
>
> *tag* - Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the
> fragment with FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String).
>
> *Returns*  - Returns the same FragmentTransaction instance.